# Blur background of an HTML element which has content behind it

Tags: html, css

[Vercel.com](https://vercel.com) has this nice effect on their header where it is partially opaque and has a blur effect to it:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

I want to recreate this effect on the navbar on my site but I'm not sure how. I have tried searching, but the only results I get are about blurring a *background image*.

I tried inspecting the site's CSS, but the only interesting line I found was `backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(5px);`, but this doesn't seem to do anything, see the snippets:

#### With `backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(5px);`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(5px);
}

main {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>

<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Nisl purus in mollis
  nunc sed. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Est ante in
  nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Lectus quam id leo in vitae. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet consectetur. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque
  mauris. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Justo eget magna
  fermentum iaculis eu non. Cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Aliquet enim tortor
  at auctor urna nunc id. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Non odio euismod lacinia at. Erat pellentesque
  adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Aliquam
  nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Lobortis feugiat
  vivamus at augue eget. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Sed enim ut sem viverra. Congue
  quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Id eu nisl nunc mi. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo
  a. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Fringilla
  phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie
  at elementum eu facilisis sed. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam
  malesuada bibendum. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Feugiat vivamus
  at augue eget arcu. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam.
</main>
```

#### Without `backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(5px);`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(5px); */
}

main {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>

<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Nisl purus in mollis
  nunc sed. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Est ante in
  nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Lectus quam id leo in vitae. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet consectetur. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque
  mauris. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Justo eget magna
  fermentum iaculis eu non. Cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Aliquet enim tortor
  at auctor urna nunc id. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Non odio euismod lacinia at. Erat pellentesque
  adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Aliquam
  nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Lobortis feugiat
  vivamus at augue eget. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Sed enim ut sem viverra. Congue
  quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Id eu nisl nunc mi. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo
  a. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Fringilla
  phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie
  at elementum eu facilisis sed. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam
  malesuada bibendum. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Feugiat vivamus
  at augue eget arcu. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam.
</main>
```

Stack Snippets doesn't even recognise the `backdrop-filter` CSS property, in the editor it is colored red, even though there is [an article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) for it:

> The `backdrop-filter` CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent.

How can I achieve this blurred background effect in CSS?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `opacity` css property?

Comment: @koder613 yes, it is in the code snippets in my post

Comment: It most defnetly is the backdrop-filter. That property is just nor supported pretty well, thus the effect only works in chrome,safari and edge for me (broken in IE and firefox) . See this https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter

Comment: @MincedMeatMole I'm on Chrome, but the effect does not appear in JSFiddle or Stack Snippets. Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: @MincedMeatMole and the blur effect on [vercel.com](https://vercel.com) works for me on both Chrome, Firefox Developer Edition, Microsoft Edge, and Edge Beta.

Comment: ok it defenetly broke in my firefox ヽ(。_°)ノ anyways I added a working snippet in the answer

Comment: Note: If anyone is considering using this blur effect as a form of paywall (as I've seen some news sites do) where a user signs-in/pays money to remove the blur effect, do take into consideration that anyone can still look at the source and read what's behind it. Simply posting the actual content and then blurring it is not an effective paywall. If you are considering that, then you need to re-consider.

Comment: I should also mention that I realize you seem to be using this as a header bar. That's perfectly fine. I just wanted to warn any future readers that come by and think of adapting this blur effect to use in a paywall.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  color: white;
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(2px);
}

main {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>

<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Nisl purus in mollis
  nunc sed. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Est ante in
  nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Lectus quam id leo in vitae. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet consectetur. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque
  mauris. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Justo eget magna
  fermentum iaculis eu non. Cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Aliquet enim tortor
  at auctor urna nunc id. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Non odio euismod lacinia at. Erat pellentesque
  adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Aliquam
  nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Lobortis feugiat
  vivamus at augue eget. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Sed enim ut sem viverra. Congue
  quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Id eu nisl nunc mi. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo
  a. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Fringilla
  phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie
  at elementum eu facilisis sed. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam
  malesuada bibendum. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Feugiat vivamus
  at augue eget arcu. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam.
</main>
```

Here is a working snippet. I think the opacity broke the backdrop-filter. Addind a background-color with rgba(255,255,255,.2) fixed it. I just fine-tuned the values for a better effect.

Comment: The reason for the opacity breaking the effect is that it creates a new stacking context. Anyting that does so will break it.

Comment: @AnnoyinC IIRC you need to enable a flag in about:flags to use backdrop-filter (may be outdated)

Answer (score 5):

Okay, So I tried a bunch of things and here's what I got to know:

- The backdrop filter doesn't work (Still not supported well) in the Firefox Browser.
- The backdrop filter doesn't work (or doesn't work well) with the *opacity* CSS property.
- For it to work (In the supported browsers like Chrome) you have to add the *opacity* in the background color itself, so, rather than coding it like this:

```css
background: #000000;
opacity: 0.7;
```

You'd be doing something like this:

```css
background-color: #000000a1;
/* OR */
background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.631);
/* OR */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.631);
```

I changed your code a bit, so that It'll look a bit more clear. I removed the red background and added a **light gray background with black text** and I also removed the z-index and the width and replaced it with a **padding**.

So the end result would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Segoe UI, sans-serif;
    }
    
    header {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
      color: white;
      backdrop-filter: saturate(90%) blur(1px);
    }
    
    main {
      background: #eeeeee;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Nisl purus in mollis
    nunc sed. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Est ante in
    nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Lectus quam id leo in vitae. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Dolor magna eget est lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque
    mauris. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Justo eget magna
    fermentum iaculis eu non. Cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Aliquet enim tortor
    at auctor urna nunc id. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Non odio euismod lacinia at. Erat pellentesque
    adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa.
    Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Lobortis
    feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Sed enim ut sem viverra.
    Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Id eu nisl nunc mi. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor
    leo a. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra.
    Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Posuere morbi
    leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien
    nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum
    id. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam.
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's also important to note that mobile browsers often turn off backdrop filters as well, because it can turn annoying on mobiles